# How to get Mathematica to compile with target C?

Tags: compile, ccompilerdriver

I have been trying to compile some functions in mathematica with target C for speed.

basically when I try:

```
c = Compile[ {{x, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
    Module[ {sum, inc}, sum = 1.0; inc = 1.0; 
    Do[inc = inc*x/i; sum = sum + inc, {i, n}]; sum], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

I get the following error:

```
Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function.
```

But it looks like Mathematica is already recognizing my C compiler infact If I try:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
DefaultCCompiler[]
CCompilers[Full]
CCompilers[]
```

I get:

```
CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler

{{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
  "Compiler" -> 
   CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0", 
  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Intel Compiler", 
  "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> None, 
  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Generic C Compiler", 
  "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}

{{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
  "Compiler" -> 
   CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
  "CompilerInstallation" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0", 
  "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
```

Am I doing something completely wrong? Probably yes, Anybody has an answer?

Thank you in advance

Comment: your code works for me using GCC. this suggests its a configuration problem with your compiler or how it interacts with mathematica.

Comment: Thanks, also for the edit! you are probably right because in my mac OSX the code works just fine. I am wondering if there is  a way of specifying one particular compiler.

Comment: You have the Windows SDK installed? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html. Also you can set things like `$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:/MinGW-w64", 
   "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe"};`

Comment: Latest version Windows SDK installed a couple of days ago.

Comment: Try evaluating ``Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print}`` to see the compiler output

Comment: What @Simon said, but include both ``Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print, "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print}``.  It will show you both the compiler command line and any errors the compiler shows.  This is likely due to something going wrong during compiling C code to an executable, e.g. missing libraries.  I don't think it's a problem with compiling Mathematica to C or with finding the C compiler

Comment: Hi guys, just an update. I updated to Mathematica 10 and now it works without problems. Sorry I could not find a solution for Mathematica 9.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a system configuration issue -  the OP upgraded to V10 and no longer had any problems, so any answer is unlikely to benefit other users.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible even on version 9. Question should indeed be closed.